# Can a cat drink human milk?

Tags: cats, health, diet

My mom always gives our cat human milk, because our cat loves it.
But I'm scared because it might be bad for him, even though he likes it. And I heard that it's bad for cats to drink milk because they are lactose intolerant

Is it bad for cat to drink human milk?

Comment: Do you mean cow milk, or some other non-human milk that humans typically drink?

Comment: Or milk from a human woman?

Comment: Please answer the questions in the comments, or accept the given answer. If you do not do so, your question may be closed, because it is not clear if you speak about milk given from a human mother, or milk usually consumed by humans (from cow, goat or similar)

Comment: oh im sorry, i meant human milk

Comment: wait, it says "human milk" on the title right?

Answer (score 7):

**It is not recommended to give adult cats milk.**

As far as I know, all mammal milk contains lactose, though how much depends on the species the milk came from.  And generally, all mammals, including cats, are lactose intolerant as adults. Humans are the exception for having a significant portion of the adult population able to digest it.

**What happens if a cat does eat lactose?**

Cats that eat lactose will end up with symptoms similar to a lactose intolerant human:  painful stomach cramps, bloating, gas, vomiting, dehydration, constipation, or diarrhea. It can also increase the cat's heart rate.

It's even possible to kill the cat if it gets such excessive diarrhea it ends up dangerously dehydrated.  I doubt your cat is at risk of that happening, however, since I doubt your mother would give the cat milk if it experienced such an obvious reaction to it.  Most people who give their cats dairy do so because they fail to notice the symptoms of lactose intolerance, and so assume that it's fine.

**In conclusion, do not give your cats regular milk.**

Besides the problems with lactose, milk is not really good for them from a nutrition standpoint either, and so they should not be given dairy as meals regardless.

However, if she really insists on giving them milk as a treat, there are milk based cat treat products out there. These products have had any lactose removed. They also usually come in appropriate serving sizes for cats. Or, at minimum, look for lactose free milk.